# A question about the Henningson-Skenderis holographic Weyl anomaly calculation.

Tags: ads-cft, holographic-principle, quantum-anomalies

I am referring to this very famous paper. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9806087

- I am referring to equations 20 and 27 and 28. Anyone can help derive them?

---

I vaguely think that they substituted equation 9 in the bulk part of equation 10 and power series expanded in $\rho$ and isolated the "log" term in the integral to get 20 and 27. But (1) I am not seeing how this calculation is done and (2) how does $g_2$ and $g_4$ and $g_0$ (all of which look like arbitrary functions!) get repackaged in terms of curvature tensors (as in 28)!?